# Recover from android factory reset?

Tags: data-recovery

I "accidentally" did factory reset my sister's phone. I'm interested in trying out AccessData FTK Imager but the problem is i don't know how to load the android filesystem for insepection?

Or more broadly, how to recover from factory reset. No backups, no google sync.

Comment: Why do I feel that this is SPAM?

Comment: @Firelord know what you mean, but it seems legitimate enough. Even if it is SPAM, some later user could use it

Comment: seems spammy :/

Comment: not a spam. if this is somehow a duplicate, take the appropriate measures. It's not that I don't trust google results, it's just that I trust this site.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to roll back a factory reset. There are, however, ways to recover data from the internal drive.

As always, if your are dealing with a potentially catastrophic loss scenario make a copy of the current state. The time-tested way is to clone the state by using dd via the adb (Android Debug Bridge) tool from the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). [Guymager](http://guymager.sourceforge.net/) may be an alternative but I haven't used it for this purpose yet.

- [Here is slightly out-of-date how-to using dd.](http://freeandroidforensics.blogspot.de/2014/08/live-imaging-android-device.html)
- [Here is a how-to that only relies on Android tools.(Android 4+ only)](http://www.howtogeek.com/125375/how-to-create-a-full-android-phone-or-tablet-backup-without-rooting-or-unlocking-your-device/)

After creating a clone you can attach the phone to a PC and try your luck with Testdisk or the less powerful but easier to use Recuva (MS Windows only). If this is not working out, bring in the big guns.

Get a copy of [Paladin](http://www.sumuri.com/products/paladin/) (it includes Autopsy/Sleuth-Kit, a powerful forensics tool) and start digging. Be warned, this can take a long time.

Comment: How did you say you can use Recuva for the dd image? I tried mounting the image using OSFMount and it mounts as a ext3 filesystem, for what it's worth. Now Recuva see's the partition but treats it as invalid.